# How to get the unparsed query string from a http request in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I can use the below to get the query string.

```
  var query_string = request.query;
```

What I need is the raw unparsed query string.  How do I get that? For the below url the query string is `{ tt: 'gg' }`, I need `tt=gg&hh=jj` etc....

```
http://127.0.0.1:8065?tt=gg

Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8065
{ tt: 'gg' }
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `node`'s [URL](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) module as per [this](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) example:

```
require('url').parse(request.url).query
```

e.g.

```
node> require('url').parse('?tt=gg').query
'tt=gg'
```

Or just go straight to the url and `substr` after the `?`

```
var i = request.url.indexOf('?');
var query = request.url.substr(i+1);
```

(which is what `require('url').parse()` does under the hood)

Comment: How do I get the raw?  request.query == { tt: 'gg' }.  I want tt=gg.

Comment: That's what the answer does. You may want to note that `query` above is not `request.query`. The latter is a member added by express.

Comment: I do not use express.  I need to be lightweight

Comment: Sorry, in that case you need to add more code as `query` is not a member of the `request` object in the core node library. That's why I thought you were using express. Regardless, the answer just uses the core node modules.

Comment: @Tampa: what do you even mean by "lightweight"? What do you really want, and how is one thing vs. another lightweight?

Comment: Use of the `parse` method is [discouraged](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) now.  Use `new URL(req.url).search` instead, or `new URL(req.url, 'https://yourbasehere.com/').search` if you're not sure whether `reg.url` is absolute or relative. See: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_search

Comment: For security stuff you can pass option like this `require('url').parse(request.url, true).query`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`req.originalUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) in express 3.x+.  (Older versions can use [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) from node's http module.)  This should produce the raw string, excluding the `?`:

```
var query_index = req.originalUrl.indexOf('?');
var query_string = (query_index>=0)?req.originalUrl.slice(query_index+1):'';
// 'tt=gg&hh=jj' or ''
```

Note that if you have [a `#` to denote the end of the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924160/is-it-valid-to-have-more-than-one-question-mark-in-a-url/2924187#2924187), it will not be recognized.

If you want to pass the string along to a new URL, you should include the `?`:

```
var query_index = req.originalUrl.indexOf('?');
var query_string = (query_index>=0)?req.originalUrl.slice(query_index):'';
// '&tt=gg&hh=jj' or ''
res.redirect('/new-route'+query_string);
// redirects to '/newroute?tt=gg&hh=jj'
```

Comment: `req.url.split('?')[1]` would work incorrectly for **valid** URLs, containing more than one `?` symbol.

Comment: Hot damn, you're right!  But the last `?` is always gonna be the start of the query, right?  Let me fix that right quick...

Comment: Nope, [the _first_ `?` always marks the start of the query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924187/3006854).  So I'll switch to `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 2):

Express uses [`parseurl`](https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl) which stores [`_parsedUrl`](https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl/blob/master/index.js#L54) in the `request` object. Original [string query](https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl/blob/master/index.js#L112) can be accessed via [`request._parsedUrl.query`](https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl/blob/master/index.js#L134).

Comment: `req.parsedUrl` is not part of the documented Express API and is thus subject to change in a future release and break your code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var queryString = Object.keys(request.query).map(key => key + '=' + request.query[key]).join('&');
```

or

```js
var queryString = require('querystring').stringify(request.query);
```

Comment: The first approach can lead to security issues as you do not escape characters. You should at least `encodeURIComponent(...)` both the keys and values. Also it will not work for arrays and objects passed in query string. But the second option is secure :)