# URL parameters and backbone routing

Tags: http, url, backbone.js

Backbone.js maintains routing information in a URL after the hash mark, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:3000#page/hardware/table/?action=details&actionTargetId=5&actionTargetName=10.3.177.185&actionTarget=host
```

Even though the routing information is in the format ?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3, this portion is not technically part of the url query string since it comes after the hash mark.

My question is if I add an actual query string to our app's urls like this:

```
http://localhost:3000?newparam=newvalue#page/hardware/table/?action=details&actionTargetId=5&actionTargetName=10.3.177.185&actionTarget=host
```

is there any possibility of the "newparam" url parameter interfering with the backbone portion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid to have more than one question mark in a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924160/is-it-valid-to-have-more-than-one-question-mark-in-a-url)

Answer (score -1):

the problem is your not actually creating a legit query string. your mixing your route with your parameters.

your example is formatted as:
`domain ? param # route ? other params`

as soon as a questionmark appears in a url everything after it is interpreted as a query string. (in this case) even your route.

personally i suggest using the html5 pushstate.

`Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})`

this will give you clean(er) urls

`http://localhost:3000/page/hardware/table/?newparam=newvalue&action=details&actionTargetId=5&actionTargetName=10.3.177.185&actionTarget=host`

that will help your routes to not interfere with your parameters.