# Regex Return Number between last / and?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to select the id at the end of a URL between the final `/` and before the first `?`
example: `http://www.website.com/page/support/28685875?JK.kj_id=`

Would extract only the id: `28685875`

I'm pretty awful at regex and have figured out these

- `([^/]+$)`  selects the end `28685875?JK.kj_id=`
- `.+?(?=\?)` selects the start `www.website.com/page/support/28685875`

I thought to try and combine these together in various ways but after a few hours I've had no success.

Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong / how to select this URL portion?

**Edit**: I am using aa java based ETL application to transform datasets.

Comment: From the regex tag info: "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also **include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool**."

Comment: When speaking about parsing URLs in Java, I'd recommend using [URL class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). Unless there are more strict requirements, this seems the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NON-REGEX SOLUTION

In Java, you can use [URL class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to parse URLs. So, the best solution would be:

```
URL aURL = new URL("http://www.website.com/page/support/28685875?JK.kj_id=");
String str = aURL.getPath().substring(aURL.getPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
System.out.println(str);
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/F5FlVS)

See [Parsing a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) tutorial.

## REGEX SOLUTION

The regex that you are looking for should match the last `/` followed by digits or any symbols up to `?` that might also followed by optional characters other than `/` to the end of string. The part between `/` and `?` can be *captured* into a group and then used.

```
\/([^\/]*)\?[^\/]*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB3pL3/1)

The negated character class `[^\/]` matches any character but a `/`. Group 1 will hold the value you need.

To only *match* the substring you need to use lookarounds:

```
(?<=/)[^/]*(?=[?][^/]*$)
^^^^^      ^^^
```

or a simpler one:

```
(?<=/)[^/?]+(?=[?]|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE2lL8/1)

[Java code](http://ideone.com/N2Vjox):

```
String s = "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/page/support/28685875?JK.kj_id=";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=/)[^/?]+(?=[?]|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
}
```

However, you can use a capturing based regex and access the Group 1 using `matcher.group(1)`.

The `(?<=/)([^/?]+)(?=[?]|$)` pattern does the following:

- `(?<=/)` - checks if there is a `/` before the currently tested position in the string (if failed, the index is advanced, next position is tested)
- `[^/?]+` - matches 1 or more characters other than `/` and `?` (no escaping necessary here)
- `(?=[?]|$)` - checks if the next character is `?` or end of string. If not, fail the match.

Comment: Depending on what platform/tool/language you are using, the right solution may be other than regex. Only use this if you are bound to use regex.

Comment: I added a lookaround based solution

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, In my last few hours of elarnign regex I bashed my head against these ?<=/ lookbacks and couldnt get them to work. 

This looks like the code I was trying to write but yours worked, I'll have to compare it and test it more when I wake up.

sorry for the lack of details in original post, edidted that its a java based etl tool

Comment: You are correct about looking to other tools for URL parsing. But most of the time I prefer regex above string parsing: You can separate implementation and context (a pattern can even be given in a config file), a regex can be tested without the need of the implementation and exceptions on a regex are more predictable than exceptions on string parsing (what happens if there is no "/" in the input? what happens if "/" is the last character?)

Comment: @AutomatedChaos: Lots of SO users believe a regex should not be used if the job can be done without it. Here, the requirement is *get the substring after the last `/` up to the first `?` after it if any*. So, if the `/` is at the end, the result will be [an empty string](http://ideone.com/xiHZlZ) as expected. If there is no `/`, also, an [empty string get returned since the path is empty](http://ideone.com/n87ziY) (so, it will return the whole string as is since `lastIndexOf` will return -1, then we add up +1, and get the 0 index as starting point for the `substring`). This is safe to use.

Comment: I would not recommend non-regex option if I was not sure it is efficient for the current scenario. Unless there are stricter requirements (like protocol can go missing), I'd really recommend using that option.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\/([^\/\?]+)(?:\?|$)
```

This will fetch any character after last "/" and before "?", if "?" exists. Here the first group will provide you the ID.

simplified

```
(?<=\/)([^\/\?]+)(?=\?|$)
```

This will fetch the ID without grouping.

Comment: I think it should work, too. Note that `?` does not have to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: I dont think url have more than one "?" . Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Well, as I say, it should work too in this case. As for `?`, there can be more than one in a URL, see [Is it valid to have more than one question mark in a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924160/is-it-valid-to-have-more-than-one-question-mark-in-a-url)

Comment: This seems to work amazingly. Thank you I can go to sleep peacefully now to wakeup for work in 4 hours.

One followup question: How could I modify it to exclude the / and ? from the final result?

Comment: cant understand the followup question. please explain ?

Comment: disregard followup question, I misunderstood the regex. Your solution seems to work perfectly, i will need to test it in the morning though. thank you for your time.