# using params in $http.post doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to deconstruct this url

**this works**

```
$http.post('http://mysrc:8080/calc?country=Usa&city=NewYork', {
          {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==' }
});
```

to use params insted

**this doesn't work**

```
  $http.post('http://mysrv:8080/calc?', {
                    params: { country: "Usa", city: "NewYork" },
                    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==', }
                });
```

Comment: Why would you use POST with no data? `params` is for GET

Comment: `$http.get('http://mysrv:8080/calc', {params: {country: 'Usa', city:'NewYork'},headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='}});` Does this work?

Comment: @ShamSUP I don' t think the problem is the "?" since any extra question mark will be traded as a literal...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924160/is-it-valid-to-have-more-than-one-question-mark-in-a-url

Comment: Actually I swapped the post method for the get method

Answer (score 0):

It's janky to use url params on a post. Traditionally data like you have goes in the body, commonly url encoded but in any case should match the header indicating the encoding.

See: [HTTP POST with URL query parameters -- good idea or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611906/http-post-with-url-query-parameters-good-idea-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood how [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) works.  Try this:

```
 $http({params: { country: "Usa", city: "NewYork" },
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==' }})
 $http.post('http://mysrv:8080/calc?');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#shortcut-methods).

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

So for your example:

```
$http.post('/someUrl', null, {
                params: { country: "Usa", city: "NewYork" },
                headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==' }
            });
```

But as others mentioned - since you don't post any data to the server, why use `.post`?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this.

```
$http({
    method: 'post', 
    url : "https://myserver.com/api/v1/name", 
    data : {
        fname : "Senthil",
        lname : "Kumar"
    }
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic token_hash'
    }
});
```