# Can a valid URL usefully contain more than 1 question mark?

Tags: web, url, parameters

URLs can obviously contain 0 question marks, e.g. `www.google.com`

Or they could contain exactly 1 question mark e.g. `www.google.com?q=soccer`

So far, I can see that most (all?) URL's *still work* when more '?' characters are added, and I also know that [query strings are non-standard and implementation is client-specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding), so, if I interpret that correctly, technically there's nothing *stopping* a developer from having URL's containing many ?'s, but it just might not fit within standard conventions.

Example: something like this still works, even though it's an odd URL: `https://www.google.com/?????????`

#### Question

So my question is can a valid url contain more than one question mark, and are the superfluous question marks ever useful? (obviously 1 question mark serves a very important purpose in many URL's - to delineate between the domain and the parameters)

#### Backgorund

Why would anyone care? I'm making a method that accepts a URL, and I'll provide a warning if there's > 1 question mark. (but I won't provide that warning if there are valid reasons for > 1 question mark in typical day to day use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a great question and has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924160/is-it-valid-to-have-more-than-one-question-mark-in-a-url#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20it%20is%20valid.,the%20end%20of%20the%20URI.).

Obviously, it is not something common that we usually see (some places even say that this should be not allowed), but I'm going to show a few more practical examples of that. Even though it is not common, I believe that "preventing URLs" with two question marks may not be so good and in the end, I'll say why.

**Simple URL redirect service**

Let's say that some redirection service has a code more or less like this:

```php
<?php

if ($_GET['redirect_to']) {
  $url = $_GET['redirect_to'];
  if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    //valid URL, redirect
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");;
    header("Location: " . $url);
    die;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the code first validates the URL, if valid, redirect the user. If you access this, it will work:

http://localhost/?redirect_to=https://www.example.com/content?from=https://api.example.com/posts?id=2

There are multiple question marks there, one to define the `redirect_to` parameter, another one to the `from` parameter, and the last to the `id` parameter of the redirected URL. To PHP, all this (redirect_to content) is a valid URL. Also, the StackOverflow editor highlights the whole URL as a valid link (the generated answer does not, but I will keep it this way and you can check that if try to edit).

**API's**

You can download the [JSON Placeholder API](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder) and create a new post on `data.json` like this:

```js
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Is multiple question marks useful??",
  "body": "Maybe"
}
```

After running with `npm start`, you can access `http://localhost:3000/posts?title=Is%20multiple%20question%20marks%20useful??` and the post will be returned, so, this would be an example where someone would like to return a post that contains the question mark.

**HOWEVER**

It's pretty obvious that using multiple question marks on the URL is very weird, and not all clients can interpret this correctly, so it might also be a bad practice to build a system that **generates** this kind of URL. But your question is about to **validate** or not multiple question marks, so, thinking that those URLs can belong to other services that you don't have control, to me, there's no need to do the validation.