# Remove a parameter to the URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Original URL:

```
http://yourewebsite.php?id=10&color_id=1
```

Resulting URL:

```
http://yourewebsite.php?id=10
```

I got the function adding Param

```
function insertParam(key, value){
    key = escape(key); value = escape(value);
    var kvp = document.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    var i=kvp.length; var x; while(i--) 
    {
        x = kvp[i].split('=');

        if (x[0]==key)
        {
            x[1] = value;
            kvp[i] = x.join('=');
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i<0) {kvp[kvp.length] = [key,value].join('=');}

    //this will reload the page, it's likely better to store this until finished
    document.location.search = kvp.join('&'); 
}
```

but I need to function to remove Param

Comment: Just a sidenote - you didn' open the curly,brackets after declaring your function.

Comment: We need more details: remove based on what? Only the last? Based on the key?

Comment: If you only want the first parameter (id), you could `split("&")[0];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guy. I got the code from this question here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript. And I just want to reverse the code to remove the adding parameter url.
I not good in javascript.

Comment: In the same question there is a class which can also remove parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/487103/1266242

Comment: An easy way to get this is: "http://yourewebsite.php?id=10&color_id=1".split("?")[0]

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try this. Just pass in the param you want to remove from the URL and the original URL value, and the function will strip it out for you.

```
function removeParam(key, sourceURL) {
    var rtn = sourceURL.split("?")[0],
        param,
        params_arr = [],
        queryString = (sourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? sourceURL.split("?")[1] : "";
    if (queryString !== "") {
        params_arr = queryString.split("&");
        for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            param = params_arr[i].split("=")[0];
            if (param === key) {
                params_arr.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        if (params_arr.length) rtn = rtn + "?" + params_arr.join("&");
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

To use it, simply do something like this:

```
var originalURL = "http://yourewebsite.com?id=10&color_id=1";
var alteredURL = removeParam("color_id", originalURL);
```

The var `alteredURL` will be the output you desire.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow!Thanks. It really help's me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if it strips all parameters, you would want to not use this line:
rtn = rtn + "?" + params_arr.join("&");

you'd want to test if params_arr.length > 0 first.

Comment: You may look in the other answer i edited to push your new url directly to the url bar .

Comment: nice. Altered it with simple checking in the end for params_arr length, so we don't get "?" if there are no more get params left. Like so: if (params_arr.length > 0) {
        rtn = rtn + "?" + params_arr.join("&");
      }

Comment: here negative loop is intentional, `for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {` it will remove if parameter is include multiple times.

Comment: doesn't work well when having multiple params

Comment: a good function, but it also cuts ancor, if it goes after removed parameter, for example, if we have a link like www.site.com/index.php?a=1&b=2#ancor, while cutting the "b" parameter ancor will be also removed. How we can avoid this?

Answer (score 16):

```
function removeParam(parameter)
{
  var url=document.location.href;
  var urlparts= url.split('?');

 if (urlparts.length>=2)
 {
  var urlBase=urlparts.shift(); 
  var queryString=urlparts.join("?"); 

  var prefix = encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
  var pars = queryString.split(/[&;]/g);
  for (var i= pars.length; i-->0;)               
      if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0)!==-1)   
          pars.splice(i, 1);
  url = urlBase+'?'+pars.join('&');
  window.history.pushState('',document.title,url); // added this line to push the new url directly to url bar .

}
return url;
}
```

This will resolve your problem

Comment: Have combined the window.history.pushState with the replacement from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7171293/2067690 - works well.

Comment: I'd use document.location.search instead of just splitting, and it needs something like this added to preserve hash
    if (document.location.hash) {
        url = url + document.location.hash;
    }

Comment: I would use `replaceState` instead of `pushState`. It's a matter of opinion, but I don't think that removing a parameter from the url should be a new history state.

Comment: This seems more easy way to do https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete