# Pass parameter to function onclick jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting, extract

I am trying to remove the parameters from the URL with jquery. Actually parameters have to be passed dynamically and should be the text of parent element on click. Then after adding a prefix to that, I need to pass that to function.

As in image shown below, when someone clicks the Clear link, it fetches the filter name from its heading title ie **COLOR**, after adding some prefix, say **js_**, then pass this **js_color** to function.

Till now, I have done something like this but it doesn't seems to work. Can you please help me out.

Thanks

**Edit:**

If I pass param value manually, it is working fine.

**Working**: removeParam("js_color", url)

**Not Working**: removeParam(param, url)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jz1dyh9r/

Function not getting value for 1st parameter.

[image]

```
    // Append Clear Link to element
    $('.woof_redraw_zone .woof_container_inner h4').each(function(){
        $(this).append('<a class="clear_filters">Clear</a>');
    });

    // Extract parameter, pass it to function and generate new URL
    $('.woof_redraw_zone .woof_container_inner h4').click(function(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        var prefix = ("pa_");
        var key = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text().toLowerCase();
        var param = prefix + key;
        var alteredURL = removeParam(param, url);
        console.log( removeParam(param, url) );
        // window.location.href = alteredURL;
    });
```

// Reference: [Remove a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941104/remove-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

```
    function removeParam(key, sourceURL) {
        var rtn = sourceURL.split("?")[0],
            param,
            params_arr = [],
            queryString = (sourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? sourceURL.split("?")[1] : "";
        if (queryString !== "") {
            params_arr = queryString.split("&");
            for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
                param = params_arr[i].split("=")[0];
                if (param === key) {
                    params_arr.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            rtn = rtn + "?" + params_arr.join("&");
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```

Comment: And what do you get if you log `param` and `url` ?

Comment: If I pass param manually, it is working fine

Comment: So evidently `param` is not what you think it is, and again, did you try logging it to the console.

Comment: I tried with console but no success.

Comment: Could you create a jsbin or similar?

Comment: So `console.log(param, url)` is *"not successful"*, what does that mean ?

Comment: In console I am getting values for both the parameters. but couldn't find where the actual issue is.

Comment: what about the type of each variable? you're using '===' comparison, which also compares type

Comment: Jameson, you have the code, what do you recommend me to adjust in that?

Comment: Jocob: here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jz1dyh9r/)

Comment: ok, found you're problem - you have spaces in your'e key string. change you're comparison to `param.trim() === key.trim()` and you're good to go

Comment: Thanks Jameson. You are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparison strings may have spaces and line breaks wrapping them, use `trim()` on the strings before comparing them

```
function removeParam(key, sourceURL) {
        var rtn = sourceURL.split("?")[0],
            param,
            params_arr = [],
            queryString = (sourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? sourceURL.split("?")[1] : "";
        if (queryString !== "") {
            params_arr = queryString.split("&");
            for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
                param = params_arr[i].split("=")[0];
                if (param.trim() === key.trim()) { // compare trimmed strings
                    params_arr.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            rtn = rtn + "?" + params_arr.join("&");
        }
        return rtn;
    }
```