# How to remove some parameters from an URL string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, url

I have this `var` storing a string that represents a URL full of parameters. I'm using AngularJS, and I'm not sure if there is any useful module (or maybe with plain JavaScript) to remove the unneeded URL parameters without having to use regex?

For example I need to remove `&month=05` and also `&year=2017` from:

`var url = "at merge ?derivate=21&gear_type__in=13&engine=73&month=05&year=2017"`

Comment: plain js should be fine. What have you tried?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- you mean by using the methods of the string object?

Comment: You can use String.prototype.replace for instace

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941104/remove-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941104/remove-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript) that take 2 parameters: the `param` you are trying to remove and your `source URL`:

```js
function removeParam(key, sourceURL) {
    var rtn = sourceURL.split("?")[0],
        param,
        params_arr = [],
        queryString = (sourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? sourceURL.split("?")[1] : "";
    if (queryString !== "") {
        params_arr = queryString.split("&");
        for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            param = params_arr[i].split("=")[0];
            if (param === key) {
                params_arr.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        rtn = rtn + "?" + params_arr.join("&");
    }
    return rtn;
}

var url = "at merge ?derivate=21&gear_type__in=13&engine=73&month=05&year=2017";

var url2 = removeParam("month", url);
var url3 = removeParam("year", url2);

console.log(url3);
```

---

[*Alternative solution with a regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634748/4927984)

Answer (score 15):

Use the [URLSearchParams API:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
var url = "at merge ?derivate=21&gear_type__in=13&engine=73&month=05&year=2017"
var urlParts = url.split('?');
var params = new URLSearchParams(urlParts[1]);
params.delete('month');
params.delete('year')
var newUrl = urlParts[0] + '?' + params.toString()
console.log(newUrl);
```

The advantage of using this API is that it works with and creates strings with correct [percent encoding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

For more information, see [MDN Developer Reference - URLSearchParams API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this isn't supported in Internet Explorer

Comment: One URLSearchParams polyfill -- https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill

Comment: this does work BUT the method that accepts an additional value param has bad support

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can use RegExr: **((&)*year=([^&]*))|((&)*month=([^&]*))**

use:

> `url = url.replace(/(year=([^&]*))|(month=([^&]*))/g, '');`

Read more regex :)...

```
function removeParam(name, url){
     return url.replace('/((&)*' + name + '=([^&]*))/g','');
}
```

```js
var url = "?derivate=21&gear_type__in=13&engine=73&month=05&year=2017"

function removeParam(name, _url){
         var reg = new RegExp("((&)*" + name + "=([^&]*))","g");
         return _url.replace(reg,'');
}

url = removeParam('year', url);
url = removeParam('month', url);

document.getElementById('url-replace').innerHTML = url;
```

```html
<div id="url-replace"></div>
```

Comment: From the question: "Is there is any useful module to remove the unneeded URL parameters **without having to use regex**".

Comment: Opps. that my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Using string replace:

```js
var url = "at merge ?derivate=21&gear_type__in=13&engine=73&month=05&year=2017";
var modifiedUrl = url.replace('&month=05','').replace('&year=2017','');
console.log(modifiedUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Convert the params to an object and then just use `delete params.year delete params.month` and convert it back and add it to the original url

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

console.log(location.search);
//=> '?foo=bar'

const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed);
//=> {foo: 'bar'}

console.log(location.hash);
//=> '#token=bada55cafe'

const parsedHash = queryString.parse(location.hash);
console.log(parsedHash);
//=> {token: 'bada55cafe'}

parsed.foo = 'unicorn';
parsed.ilike = 'pizza';

const stringified = queryString.stringify(parsed);
//=> 'foo=unicorn&ilike=pizza'

location.search = stringified;
// note that `location.search` automatically prepends a question mark
console.log(location.search);
//=> '?foo=unicorn&ilike=pizza'
```

Comment: you shouldn't install an npm library just for that. Npm libraries are full of sub dependencies that introduce vulnerabilities into your code.

Comment: You asked for a module... @commonSenseCode It's also easy to see what dependencies a package installs and to look at the code of the module to see if it is bigger than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Enhnaced @Mistalis's answer.

1. Return the value of the last occurrence of a param
2. Remove the `?` of the removed param was the only param
3. Url encoded the query params to ensure browser stately

```js
function pruneParams(key, url) {
  var urlParts = url.split('?');
  var rtnUrl = urlParts[0];
  var paramParts;
  var paramValue;
  var params_arr = [];
  var queryString = decodeURIComponent(urlParts[1] || '');
  if (queryString !== '') {
    params_arr = queryString.split('&');
    for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      paramParts = params_arr[i].split('=');
      if (paramParts[0] === key) {
        paramValue = paramParts[1];
        params_arr.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    if (params_arr.length) {
      var wasEncoded = url.split('&').length < 2;
      rtnUrl = rtnUrl + '?' + (wasEncoded ? encodeURIComponent(params_arr.join('&')) : params_arr.join('&'));
    }
  }
  return { url: rtnUrl, [key]: paramValue, paramCount: params_arr.length > 1 };
}

var u1 = 'http://localhost:4200/member/';
var u2 = 'http://localhost:4200/member/?ts=23423424';
var u3 = 'http://localhost:4200/member/?fooo=2342342asfasf&ts=252523525';
var u4 = 'http://localhost:4200/member?foo=234243&ts=234124124&bar=21kfafjasf&ts=223424234&dd=This Is A Line';
var u5 = 'http://localhost:4200/member?foo%3D234243%26ts%3D2242424%26bar%3D21kfafjasf%26dd%3DThis%20Is%20A%20Line';

console.log(pruneParams('ts', u1));
console.log(pruneParams('ts', u2));
console.log(pruneParams('ts', u3));
console.log(pruneParams('ts', u4));
console.log(pruneParams('ts', u5));


//   {
//     url: 'http://localhost:4200/member/',
//     ts: undefined,
//     paramCount: false,
//   }
//   {
//     url: 'http://localhost:4200/member/',
//     ts: '23423424',
//     paramCount: false,
//   }
//   {
//     url: 'http://localhost:4200/member/?fooo=2342342asfasf',
//     ts: '252523525',
//     paramCount: false,
//   },
//   {
//     url: 'http://localhost:4200/member?foo=234243&bar=21kfafjasf&dd=This Is A Line',
//     ts: '234124124',
//     paramCount: true,
//   }
//   {
//     url: 'http://localhost:4200/member?foo%3D234243%26bar%3D21kfafjasf%26dd%3DThis%20Is%20A%20Line',
//     ts: '2242424',
//     paramCount: true,
//   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from @Mistalis answer but tidied up. Useful if URLSearchParams API is not available.

```js
const removeUrlParam = function (url, param) {

   var parts = url.split('?')
   
   url = parts[0]
   if (parts.length !== 2) return url
   
   var qs = parts[1]
   if (qs === '') return url

    var params = qs.split('&')
    for (var i = params.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      var key = params[i].split('=')[0]
      if (key === param) params.splice(i, 1)
    }

    return params.length ? url + '?' + params.join('&') : url
}

var url1 = removeUrlParam('/xxxxx', 'a')
var url2 = removeUrlParam('/xxxxx?a=1', 'a')
var url3 = removeUrlParam('/xxxxx?a=1&b=2', 'a')

console.log(url1, url2, url3)
```