# How to remove the last two parts from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following URL: http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b

I want to remove the last two parts, so this would produce: http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox

I tried like this :

```
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");
var lastVar = arrVars.pop();
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
console.log(restVar);
```

It only successfully removes the last part.

I want to remove one more part.

How can I do that?

Comment: You just need to pop it again before joining.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941104/remove-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

Comment: as @AndrewLi said, just pop it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pop it again. :)

```
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");
arrVars.pop();
arrVars.pop();
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
console.log(restVar);
```

Or you could just use splice:

```
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");
arrVars.splice(-1,2)
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
console.log(restVar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply use the substring function :

```
if (vars.toLowerCase().indexOf("/detail/")!=-1)
    restVar = vars.substring(0,vars.toLowerCase().indexOf("/detail/"))
```

I think it gives you more control on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could `pop` twice, but there are other solutions.

For instance, decreasing the array's length with 2 has the same effect:

```
arrVars.length -= 2;
```

```js
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");
arrVars.length -= 2;
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
console.log(restVar);
```

But maybe consider using a regular expression:

```
vars.match(/(.*)\/.*\//)[1]
```

This is saying: grab as much as possible, as long as two forward slashes still come after it.

```js
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var restVar = vars.match(/(.*)\/.*\//)[1];
console.log(restVar);
```

Note that the input should be a valid URL. If there are no two forward slashes in your string, this will raise an exception. If you need to deal with this, and don't like `try...catch` then first test whether the `match` result is not `null`, and only then get the captured group content:

```
var restVar = vars.match(/(.*)\/.*\//);
restVar = restVar && restVar[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `pop()` twice you can use `splice()` or `slice()` like this:

**splice()** - [w3schools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

```
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");

// remove desired # of URL pieces here in 2nd parameter:
arrVars.splice(-2, 2);
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
```

**slice()** - [w3schools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

```
var vars = "http://myshop.dev/member/message/inbox/detail/58c4fad6607a1d16f0006b3b";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");
var arrLength = arrVars.length;

// remove desired # of URL pieces here:
var arrVars = arrVars.slice(0, arrLength - 2);
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to use `splice`, which mutates `arrVars` already by itself. Either use `slice`, or use `splice` without capturing the return value, but then of course with different argument values.