# Replace url parameters function

Tags: javascript, url

I got this function from [here in stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171099/how-to-replace-url-parameter-with-javascript-jquery) to replace url parameters like that :

```
function replaceUrlParam(paramName, paramValue){
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var pattern = new RegExp('('+paramName+'=).*?(&|$)') 
    var newUrl = currentUrl.replace(pattern,'$1' + paramValue + '$2');
    if(newUrl == currentUrl){
        newUrl = newUrl + (newUrl.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue 
    }
    window.history.pushState('',document.title,newUrl);
    return newUrl;
}
```

> www.mysite.com/index.php?id=14&&cat=20

and i use it like that:

```
replaceUrlParam('id', 15);
```

like that works fine.

But the problem is it duplicates the id if i use same id which is in the url like that.

```
replaceUrlParam('id', 14)--will give--->www.mysite.com/index.php?id=14&&cat=20&&id=14
```

How can i change this function to not give duplicates when its same id ?
Thanks

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dw8gh9j/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4dw8gh9j/ seems to work for me if I hard-code your example.  Are you sure `window.location.href` is what you expect?

Comment: @dckuehn it didnt work , [http://jsfiddle.net/4dw8gh9j/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/4dw8gh9j/1/) as i said it duplicates when it same id .

Comment: sorry, I often read too quickly for my own good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement in the function explains everything. If the url hasn't changed then it tacks the param/value onto the end. Sounds like you want to also check that the value isn't already in there, like:

```
if(newUrl == currentUrl && newUrl.indexOf(paramName+'='+paramValue) === -1) {
    //...
}
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dw8gh9j/4/)

Answer (score 1):

`www.mysite.com/index.php?id=14&&cat=20`

and

`replaceUrlParam('id', 14)`

is trying to repalce id:14 with id:14.  So in this case: `newUrl == currentUrl` will resolve to `true`.

`newUrl = newUrl + (newUrl.indexOf('?')>0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue`

will find the index of the '?', which is 24, which is > 0.

So in the end you're doing this:

`newUrl = www.mysite.com/index.php?id=15&&cat=20 + paramName + '=' + paramValue`

In either scenario, if your `(currentUrl == newUrl) == true` your concatanation will end up either doing 
`newUrl = newUrl + '&' + paramName + '=' + paramValue` 
or
`newUrl = newUrl + '?' + paramName + '=' + paramValue`

Either way will duplicate your value at the end.