# Modify a parameter in url with page reload using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a url like `result?graphType=default&product=xyzzzz&shop=11`

I just want to change value of graphType, when user clicks a button.
On click of that button i store some value in a variable, and i want to replace graphType=default with `graphType=my_new_value` in my url without reload.
I don't understand how to split url at graphType= .
and even if I am able to split to url at graphType, how can I replace default (which can be something else as well depending on user options) with my variable

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171099/how-to-replace-url-parameter-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: You could start with `window.location.search` to return any url parameters...

Comment: `url without reload` : as soon as you change the URL; browser will reload it. Its a part of URL which you are going to change and hence reload. Its not in your hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your solution should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var queries = {};
    $.each(document.location.search.substr(1).split('&'), function(c,q){
        var i = q.split('=');
        queries[i[0].toString()] = unescape(i[1].toString()); // change escaped characters in actual format
    });

    // modify your parameter value and reload page using below two lines
    queries['your key']='your value';

    document.location.href="?"+$.param(queries); // it reload page
    //OR
    history.pushState({}, '', "?"+$.param(queries)); // it change url but not reload page
});
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to hear from you.. dont forget to give up vote and mark as correct.. I strangly like heaps word :D

Comment: please do up vote also, now you have enough repuaions 15+, thanks

Comment: Thanks for ur good answer. just a question. is it possible to make the browser work with the pushed state on history back? when I click the history back button of browser, pushed states don't work... only after a refresh, those are applied to page content. anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @TaiJinYuan , I think You need to use pop method for history back, hope it will be work.