# Remove Single Variable from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I currently have the following:

```
    $( "#Coupon" ).keyup(function() {
    $(this).val (function () {
        return this.value.toUpperCase();
    })      
    var url = window.location.href;
    var addon = $('#voucher').val();
    $("#ApplyCoupon").attr('href', url + "&coupon=" + addon);
```

which checks a text field and then adds the content to a url variable to check if the coupon is vali the next time the page loads.

My issue is that if you check multiple coupons, it keeps adding &coupon=blah

Is there any way of just replacing the coupon variable in the URL instead of creating new ones?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov how would I integrate that with the possibility of there not being the coupon variable already?

Comment: sorry, the link in my previous comment was not quite appropriate, so I removed the comment. But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171099/how-to-replace-url-parameter-with-javascript-jquery) looks like your question. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171099/how-to-replace-url-parameter-with-javascript-jquery#answer-20420424) answer.

Comment: Thanks bud, but where in there do I get my value from the text field?

Comment: `$("#ApplyCoupon").attr('href', replaceUrlParam(url, "coupon", addon));`