# Alter Query Strings Server Side

Tags: node.js, express, request, query-string

I have an Express application that gets search parameters and page numbers via query strings.

```
var name = req.query.name;
var state = req.query.state;
var category = req.query.category;
var pageNum = req.query.pagenum;
```

What I want is if the search query has a page number and yields no results, to do a search without the page number and pass that back to the client.  This works fine, and the front-end is receiving the data correctly.

The only thing is that I want the URL to reflect the changed page number search, so rather than being `website.com/search?page=4&state=AL` I'd like it to have the page number stripped or changed to 1.  I can do this via Javascript on the front-end, but I'd rather have the url changed on the server side (it makes more sense to me at least, rather than having to change every template to do that).

## EDIT:

Looks like the only way of doing this is to redirect to the URL without the page query string parameter.  It seems [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript) will help me out in getting this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite know your environment, but generally URLs cannot be "changed" on server-side, because they are displayed in the browser on the client-side. The user sees the last whole page request's url. You can only force an URL update (actually a page reload with different URL) from server-side with a HTTP redirect header.

You could check if there are any results for the query with page number, and if not, simply send a redirect to the URL without the page number, so the user sees that extended result with its proper (page-less) URL.

Hope it helps something.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading around and a redirect seems to be pretty much the only way of doing it (which ironically simplifies my code by a good amount).  I'm basically going to have to get the url, remove a single parameter from the query string, and redirect to that url.