# how to change the regex for locate to string of separator's query string for delete parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I working on the Query String and used the other separator or demilitator.
Now I interest for delete.

I read the question [Delete parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript) and I use the script's write of LukePH.

```
    function removeParameter(url, parameter)
{
  var urlparts= url.split('?');

  if (urlparts.length>=2)
  {
      var urlBase=urlparts.shift(); //get first part, and remove from array
      var queryString=urlparts.join("?"); //join it back up

      var prefix = encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
      var pars = queryString.split(/[&;]/g);
      for (var i= pars.length; i-->0;)               //reverse iteration as may be destructive
          if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0)!==-1)   //idiom for string.startsWith
              pars.splice(i, 1);
      url = urlBase+'?'+pars.join('&');
  }
  return url;
}
```

The separator is:

```
            Separator


javascript              Mako           

  =                       %24+
  &                       +%23+
```

In this script there is

```
var pars = queryString.split(/[&;]/g);
```

I want change the sentence for use split on the separator `+%23+`

```
var pars = queryString.split(/[+%23+;]/g);
```

This not function because contains too many values.

How to change the regex for locate to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets define a character class, as in a set of potential matches, so it makes no sense to put two of the same character in a character class. What you need to do is escape your special characters...

```
var pars = queryString.split(/\+%23\+;/g);
```