# For every ajax call the same querystring appending to the url

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, query-string

I have a ajax function which calls onclick. Actually it is a pagination function. When i click on the pagination link i am passing start variable to the url.But for me for every ajax call the same start variable appending like this. The following observed in mozilla firebug console.

For first click

```
http://127.0.0.1/testproj/ajax/pagination.php?start=2
```

for second call

```
http://127.0.0.1/testproj/ajax/pagination.php?start=2&start=4
```

for third call

```
url/ajax/pagination.php?start=2&start=4&start=6
```

But generally it should work like this for every call the only start limit need to be pass to start variable.Below is my ajax pagination function , please suggest me where i am doing wrong/mistakes.

```
    function getUEOPaginate(start)
    {
    var qstring = "start="+start;
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        data : qstring,
        url: "ajax/pagination.php",
            success:function(valid_result){                                                    
                 if(valid_result)
                  {
                        jQuery('#paginate_div').html(valid_result);
                  }                 
              }
            });
    }
```

Please help me in this regard...Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript

Comment: how are you calling function?

Comment: HI, I am calling that function onclick.

Answer (score 0):

1. First take URL - document.URL
2. Append the url with your new query string

   url : document.URL + "&start="+start,

Comment: sorry , its not working for me eventhough it is adding start=2&start=4 like that

Comment: HI All,I have solved this one by using uri. Previously i am calling this complete url like http://127.0.0.1/proj/ajax/filename.php?start=start. But now i am calling this as /ajax/filename.php?start=start. Thanks for every one.