# Remove part of URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, split

How would I remove part of a URL with jQuery, when the said part is changeable?

E.g. how can I remove this from my URL: ?modal=name

when 'name' might be *name1* *name2* or *name3*

I guess I will need to split the URL, but how do I do this when the modal name might be anything?

Comment: Wouldn't you just replace the modal name value with name1, name2,...?

Comment: Just in case you only want to remove the `modal` parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'http://yourdomain.com/search?modal=name';

alert(url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?')));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rq2han2/)

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked "How to remove the part of a URL" using jQuery

Here is a basic workaround for you:

```js
//the URL ( decode it just for GOOD practice)
var someRandomUrl = decodeURI("http://example.com?modal=name");

//here we do the splitting
var splittedParts = someRandomUrl.split("?");

// the first part of the array will be URL you will require
var theURL = splittedParts[0];

// the second part of the array will be the Query String
var theQuery = splittedParts[1];
alert(theURL);
```