# how to remove the particular string from the url and update it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the string from the url and update as it after the removal.

example: `www.abc.com/xyz`

I need to remove xyz and update it as `www.abc.com`

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: Try browser location api, It has location.hostname property which will return the name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove part of URL with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250077/remove-part-of-url-with-jquery)

Comment: wdym "update it"?

Comment: Follow above given link, then `window.location.href = /* your link here */;` to update your browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get protocol, domain, and port from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941533/get-protocol-domain-and-port-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use js split method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```js
var url = 'www.abc.com/xyz';
var arr = url.split('/');
var newUrl = arr[0];
console.log(newUrl);
```

```js
/*if string the url is 'www.abc.com/xyz/pqr' and you want only 'www.abc.com/xyz' thn?*/

var url = 'www.abc.com/xyz/pqr';
var arr = url.split('/');
if(arr.length > 1){
 arr.pop();
}
var newUrl = arr.join('/');

console.log(newUrl);
```

Comment: if string the url is 'www.abc.com/xyz/pqr' and i want only 'www.abc.com/xyz' thn?

Comment: Thanks for review.
I have added new code as per your new url string. you may also use js pop and join method

Answer (score -1):

```js
const url = new URL("https://example.com/test")
url.pathname = "/"

console.log(url.toString())
```

Comment: This feature is available in Web Workers.