# Javascript double string.replace()

Tags: javascript

i'm struggling with some magic. I'm trying to remove parametr value from URL on click:

```
 function removeParam(name, value) {
    var newUrl = window.location.href.split("?")[0],
            sourceURL = window.location.href,
    param,
    params_arr = [],
    queryString = (sourceURL.indexOf("?") !== -1) ? sourceURL.split("?")[1] : "";
if (queryString !== "") {
    params_arr = queryString.split("&");
    for (var i = params_arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        param = params_arr[i].split("&")[0];
        if (param.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
            if (params_arr[i].indexOf("%s") !== -1) {
                params_arr[i] = param.replace("%s" + value , "");
                params_arr[i] = param.replace(value , "");

            }
            else {
                params_arr[i] = param.replace(name + "=" + value, "");
            }
        }
    }
    if (params_arr[0] !== "") {
        newUrl = newUrl + "?" + params_arr.join("&");
    }

}
window.history.pushState(null,"", newUrl);
```

Remove value **C** from **var**

Source URL: `/?var=A%sB%sC` 

URL-should-be: `/?var=A%sB`

I can have multiple parameters with corresponding values like
Source URL: `/?var=A%sB%sC&var2=D%sE%sF`

But magic is that if i add second str: `params_arr[i] = param.replace(value , "");`

It will remove only **C** without separator: **%s**

How to fix it ?

I added this second replace because i need to remove values from head.

Comment: So you want to get the URL value? What about the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) object?

Comment: I know how to do it :) I just dont understand why if i add another str.replace it will add separator. In debugger i can see that second str.replace do nothing but on the next step it magicly adding separator without any reason

Answer (score 0):

this has been answered before, try this

```
function removeURLParameter(url, parameter) {
    //prefer to use l.search if you have a location/link object
    var urlparts= url.split('?');   
    if (urlparts.length>=2) {

        var prefix= encodeURIComponent(parameter)+'=';
        var pars= urlparts[1].split(/[&;]/g);

        //reverse iteration as may be destructive
        for (var i= pars.length; i-- > 0;) {    
            //idiom for string.startsWith
            if (pars[i].lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) !== -1) {  
                pars.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        url= urlparts[0] + (pars.length > 0 ? '?' + pars.join('&') : "");
        return url;
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634841/3511012

Comment: Please do not answer questions that have been asked before. Instead, flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: good to know, thanks @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: thats another solution. And it's not helping to understand this behaviour. Why it's adding separator if i add second replace string ?

Comment: And by the way i'm not removing parameter entirely but rather some of its value. I can have string like /?var=A%sB%sC&var2=A%sB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter

Comment: read question please :) BTW this solution very slow