# How can i remove the params from the url in jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i remove parameter from the link which i made through the following script...
 this include the use of jquery and if possible please let me know the solution in the jquery script

```
 <script>
            $(function() {
                $('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
                var a =$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?startdate=' + start().StartDate +'&enddate=' + start().EndDate);
                })
            })
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete a query string parameter in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript)

Comment: you can use split like var url = $(this).attr('href').split('?')[0];

Comment: @CyberAbhay this worked thanks

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you.feel free to  mark my answer worked

Comment: @Thanks a lot could you help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156075/how-to-retain-the-selected-values-of-the-datepicker-in-gsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution of your question.

You have this function which creates url

```
$(function() {
            $('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
            var a =$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?startdate=' + start().StartDate +'&enddate=' + start().EndDate);
            })
        })
```

So to get only base url for this you can just use this simple code where i have use sample url. your may be vary

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var baseurl = $('.link').attr('href').split('?')[0];
    console.log(baseurl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="https://support.google.com/mail/answer/56256?hl=en&test=213213321312">Normal Sample URL</a>
```

Comment: $(function() {
   $('a[name="searchLink"]').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').split('?')[0]);
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?startdate=' + start().StartDate +'&enddate=' + start().EndDate + '&allRows=' +start().allRows);
   })
  })... this is the change in the method that i made