# Replace the unwanted strings from string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code that will look for any YouTube link on the page and will replace those links with iFrame and embed the videos in the iFrame.

This work fine.

But sometimes, the youtube links have some stuff at the end of the link like this:

`&t=3s` or `&t=44s` etc

I need to be able to remove those as well but I can't fine a way to do this.

This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/6tv4uebw/

**Code:**

```
$(".indiContent").html(function (e, t) {
    return t.replace(/http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?/g, '<iframe width="100%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
});
```

Couls someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript

Comment: @Goran.it, that is not related to this quetsion at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
t.replace(/http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?/g, '<iframe width="100%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>').replace(/&[^]*/,'')
```

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/hrps0e5m/](https://jsfiddle.net/hrps0e5m/)

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: This doesn't work. please either rmeove your answer or edit to explain why this works and provide a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

The `&t=3s` in the end of the url is a parameter passed by url.
You can find all of them with simple regex.

Before the return (in your code), add the following lines:

```
var regex = /&.*/;
t = t.replace(regex, "");
```

And then do whatever you want with the link without these parameters.