# remove parameter from url when page reload

Tags: javascript

I add this "**?loyal**" in url when click button of Check Yangold, to appear my third party modal. but i would like to remove when page is reload.

This is what i'm using to add "?loyal" to url when click "check yangold" Button. [here](https://yangoods.com/collections/insider-rewards/products/yg4f3801b) is my site link.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location.replace(window.location.href+"/?loyal");
}
</script>
```

is it correct script for this condition?

```
var clean_uri = location.protocol + "/?loyal" + location.host + location.pathname;
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
```

Comment: _“is it correct script for this condition?”_ - don‘t ask us right away - log the value of `clean_uri` that you are assembling there to the console, and then see if it makes sense.

Comment: let's try window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.origin+window.location.pathname);

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169659/6160662