# Removing parameters from url (js or php)

Tags: javascript, php, url, parameters

I have some parameters in url that are added when coming to a specific page, so correct page is opened. For example:
https://example.com/index.php?cCode=SFI=&cmpn=cHJvdmlkaW8=
Now, when i get to that page, i want to remove them, so they don't get passed further, but still want to keep any additional parameters, like source=facebook or whatever... I found a way to remove them with this code:

```
var urlParts = url.split('?');
var params = new URLSearchParams(urlParts[1]);
params.delete('cCode');
params.delete('cmpn');
var newUrl = urlParts[0] + '?' + params.toString();
history.pushState(null, null, newUrl);
```

But they still get forwarded when i click on a some link... Any way to do this, with js or even php?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete a query string parameter in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript)

Comment: I have found out that the code i use actually works, it looks like i have some conflict on the site i am working on specifically

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the URL object instead of the url string.

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.delete('cCode');
url.searchParams.delete('cmpn');
window.history.pushState({}, document.title, url);
```

**Be advised, the URL object is not supported on IE.**

Refer to this url polyfill for IE compatability.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-polyfill

Comment: Yes, this works also, as the code i originally used, it is just a problem with this one site, for some reason it is not working on it, but multiple people worked on it, so i have to check all... TY

Comment: Maybe the query params are being enforced via php on the server side. Good luck!