# How can I replace gsi with empty string('') from a string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the above string I want to remove **gsi** along with the value. After removing **gsi** my string should look like given below.

**Scenario 1**

```
/product/Abrasives?gsi=1
```

**Expected output**

```
/product/Abrasives
```

**Scenario 2**

```
/product/Abrasives?query=search&gsi=1
```

Expected output
/product/Abrasives?query=search

**Scenario 3**

```
/product/Abrasives?query=search&gsi=1&fname=abc
```

**Expected output**

```
/product/Abrasives?query=search&fname=abc
```

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634748/how-can-i-delete-a-query-string-parameter-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor and delete the parameter:

```js
const paths = ["/product/Abrasives?gsi=1", "/product/Abrasives?query=search&gsi=1", "/product/Abrasives?query=search&gsi=1&fname=abc"]

function removeParam(path, name) {
  const url = new URL(path, "https://a.com")
  url.searchParams.delete(name)
  return url.pathname + url.search
}

console.log(
  paths.map(p => removeParam(p, "gsi"))
)
```

---

Or you could split at `?` get the querystring and pathname separately. Use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) constructor and delete the parameter

```js
const paths = ["/product/Abrasives?gsi=1", "/product/Abrasives?query=search&gsi=1", "/product/Abrasives?query=search&gsi=1&fname=abc"]

function removeParam(path, name) {
  const [pathName, queryString] = path.split('?');
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  searchParams.delete(name);
  return pathName + searchParams
}

console.log(
  paths.map(p => removeParam(p, "gsi"))
)
```