# javascript: strip "timeseek" from URL

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript function saved as bookmarklet in my browser:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open("data:video/x-mpegurl;charset=utf-8;base64,"+btoa("#EXTM3U\n"+document.location.href))})()
```

the `document.location.href` is an URL which may contain video timeseek at the end, such as:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH6pF-gXbuw&t=77s
```

how can I remove the `&t=77s` part from the url?

Comment: Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583973/519413) in the duplicate is the current best practice approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/7014483